# Dynamic input for UDF with R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, user-defined-functions, reactive

I have a table which looks something like this construction-

```
 dataTable <- data.frame(Criteria = rep(c("C1","C2","C3"), each = 6), Type = rep(c("T1", "T2", "T3",
     "T4", "T5", "T6"), each = 3), Value_1 = rep(rnorm(1)), Value_2 = rep(rnorm(1)),Value_3 = rep(rnorm(1)))
```

I am trying to build a shiny app, which can give me a drop down box to select the criteria and types to filter and do further calculations. Normally, I should do something like this-

### server.R

```
listOfCriteria = reactive({levels(input()$Criteria})
listOfTypes = reactive({levels(input()$Type})
updatePickerInput(session, "criteria", choices = listOfCriteria)
updatePickerInput(session, "type", choices = listOfTypes
requiredOutput <- subset(input(),Criteria %in% input$criteria, Type %in% input$type)
```

But I want to do it with a UDF this time. The way I have written the UDF is thus-

```
 SummaryData <- function(inputData, CriteriaInput, TypeInput){
    SummarizedData <- subset(inputData, inputData$Criteria %in% CriteriaInput, inputData$Type %in% TypeInput) 
    %>% group_by(Criteria, Type) %>% summarise(Count = n(),
    MeanV1 = mean(Value_1, na.rm = TRUE), MaxV1 = max(Value_1, na.rm = TRUE))
    return(SummarizedData)}
```

When I try inputs like-

```
SummaryData(dataTable, "C1", "T1")
```

I expected the data to be subset by C1 and T1, and return my desired summary statistics. From the shiny drop down boxes, the second and third argument can intake multiple inputs. But, it is not working for me. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure without a MWE, but my first guess is that `SummaryData` as you've written it, probably isn't reactive.  Why do you need a user defined function (=UDF?) rather than a `reactive`?